# How to close a form with a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Todo :**

Close a form by clicking a button. 
Any solution because I tried more and I saw more method but no result. 
None of these methods work. any idea.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="button" value="Close Window" 
onclick="window.close()">
</form>

<input type="button" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL" 
onClick="self.close()">
```

Comment: How are you opening that window?

Comment: Please share snippet with opened form.

Comment: What do you mean by "_close a form_"? Do you want to hide it?

Comment: Please define "_close a form_".

Comment: Shared piece of code doesn't explain, what exactly you trying to close. Please describe problem in more detail. Here you are closing browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `window` to get closed by javascript, 
then javascript must have opened that `window` in the first place to close it.

But, there is some hack using **`"self redirection"`**, 
And the following will work easily 
 **`open(location, '_self').close();`**

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="button" value="Close Window" 
onclick="open(location, '_self').close();">
</form>

<input type="button" name="cancelvalue" value="CANCEL" 
onClick="open(location, '_self').close();">
```